# String pattern matching problem in Java

Tags: java, regex

In my program when I'm using

```
line.replaceAll("(", "_");
```

I got a `RuntimeException`:

```
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
 at Processing.processEarly(Processing.java:95)
 at Processing.main(Processing.java:34)
```

Is there any reason? How can we avoid it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The first argument to `string.replaceAll` is a regular expression, not just a string. The opening left bracket is a special character in a regex, so you must escape it:

```
line.replaceAll("\\(", "_");
```

Alternatively, since you are replacing a single character, you could use `string.replace` like so:

```
line.replace('(', '_');
```

Comment: `String.replace` can also be used for literal (non-regex) replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The error message above the stack trace is (somewhat) helpful:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Unclosed group near index 1
>       (
>        ^

(That's what I get in Java 6.) It mentions "regex", "group", and the parenthesis. If you can't see this message, you should check how you're logging/catching/displaying exceptions. It could save you some trouble in the future.